# Get values from input elements in the same row of an HTML table

Tags: javascript

I have a table where each row is a separate form:

```
<tr>
  <form method="post" action="/items/1/edit">
    <td><input type="number" id="duration[1]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="10.0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="rate[1]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="25.0"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="number" id="total[1]" value="250.0"></td>
  </form>
</tr>
<tr>
  <form method="post" action="/items/2/edit">
    <td><input type="number" id="duration[2]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="20.0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="rate[2]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="50.0"></td>
    <td><input disabled type="number" id="total[2]" value="1000.0"></td>
  </form>
</tr>
```

I'd like to have the value of the `total` input be calculated when a change is made to the `duration` or `rate` input in the same row.

My "hard coded" function works for the first row only:

```
function calculateTotal(sender) {

  // use sender.closest('');

  var durationElement = document.getElementById("duration[1]");
  var durationValue = durationElement.value;

  var rateElement = document.getElementById('rate[1]');
  var rateValue = rateElement.value;

  if ( durationValue && rateValue)
  {
    var totalValue = durationValue * rateValue;    
    
    var durationElement = document.getElementById("total[1]");
    durationElement.value = totalValue;
  }
  
}
```

I think the `element.closest()` function is the right approach, but I can't get it to work.

How do I adjust it to make it based on the row of the item being edited?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp1L9dqm/34/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the parent `tr` element and select all input elements (that are not disabled) inside that element with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class, then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum up the values and assign it to the `value` property of the input with the `disabled` attribute:

```js
function calculateTotal(sender) {
  const row = sender.closest('tr');
  const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled])');
  const sum = [...inputs].reduce((a, b) => a *= +b.value, 1);
  row.querySelector('input[disabled]').value = sum;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <form method="post" action="/items/1/edit">
        <td><input type="number" id="duration[1]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="10.0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="rate[1]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="25.0"></td>
        <td><input disabled type="number" id="total[1]" value="250.0"></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <form method="post" action="/items/2/edit">
        <td><input type="number" id="duration[2]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="20.0"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="rate[2]" onChange="calculateTotal(this);" value="50.0"></td>
        <td><input disabled type="number" id="total[2]" value="1000.0"></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```